# Sorting HashMap values in Java not giving back right order

Tags: java, sorting, hashmap

I am having some problem with sorting `HashMaps` with values in `Java`.
My code is:

```
 @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
          Map<String, Integer> scores = ((HashMap<String, Integer>) prefs.get());
          Map<String, Integer> sortedscores = sortByValues(scores);
          printMap(scores);
          System.out.println("==============");
          printMap(sortedscores);
```

the prefs.get() returns a `Map<String, ?>` which I convert to `<String, Integer >`

The sorting function:

```
public static <K, V extends Comparable<V>> Map<K, V> sortByValues(final Map<K, V> map) {
    Comparator<K> valueComparator =  new Comparator<K>() {
        public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
            int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
            if (compare == 0) return 1;
            else return compare;
        }
    };
    Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
    sortedByValues.putAll(map);
    return new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(sortedByValues);
}
public static void printMap(Map<String, Integer> unsortMap){
    for (Map.Entry entry : unsortMap.entrySet()) {
        System.out.println("Key : " + entry.getKey() 
                               + " Value : " + entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

The output is:

```
Key : John Doe Value : 1000
Key : balazs Value : 975
Key : Balazs Value : 900
Key : aladar Value : 975
Key : balazs2 Value : 975
Key : score Value : 1000
Key : house Value : 1037
==============
Key : balazs Value : 975
Key : aladar Value : 975
Key : balazs2 Value : 975
Key : Balazs Value : 900
Key : house Value : 1037
Key : John Doe Value : 1000
Key : score Value : 1000
```

The first one is the unsorted, the second is sorted.
My problem is that the second output is not in DESC order (by value)

EDIT:
If I create a hasmap myself it works fine:

```
Map<String, Integer> unsortMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        unsortMap.put("asd", 1);
        unsortMap.put("asd2r1", 5);
        unsortMap.put("house", 7);
        unsortMap.put("3", 124);
        unsortMap.put("7", 4);
        unsortMap.put("5", 6);
        unsortMap.put("6", 2);
        unsortMap.put("8", 0);
```

But if I try it with this: `Map<String, Integer> scores = ((HashMap<String, Integer>) prefs.get());` I get that wierd order.

Comment: ok, what is the problem here?

Comment: The value should be sorted DESC order, but it is 975,975,975,900,1037,1000,1000 that 1037 is not where it should be

Comment: Looks like something wrong in the comparator if your sort order is messed up.

Answer (score 2):

You comparator doesn't look like it conforms to the [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html):

```
        int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
        if (compare == 0) return 1;
        else return compare;
```

Why do you return 1 when two entries are equal ?

Comment: Tried it, but nothing happened, the output is the same

Answer (score 1):

You should basically rewrite this:

```
public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
    int compare = map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
    if (compare == 0) return 1;
    else return compare;
}
```

to:

```
public int compare(K k1, K k2) {
    return map.get(k2).compareTo(map.get(k1));
}
```

When two values are equal, you're actually saying that one is greater than the other... which doesn't make much sense. If the keys are comparable, use the natural comparison.

Comment: I have tried it, but the output is the same, except that duplicate entries are missing

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in the return sentence:

```
Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
sortedByValues.putAll(map);
return new LinkedHashMap<K,V>(sortedByValues);
```

You have a sorted map, and then you put all the pairs in a new map, so they get unsorted again. Try to do this:

```
Map<K, V> sortedByValues = new TreeMap<K, V>(valueComparator);
sortedByValues.putAll(map);
return sortedByValues;
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution:
The problem was that it was comparing Strings not integers. The conversion I tried with

```
Map<String, Integer> scores = ((HashMap<String, Integer>) prefs.get());
```

did not convert it to integer.
So I used a cycle that does it right:

```
   for (@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") Map.Entry entry : scores.entrySet()) {
       scoresInt.put(entry.getKey().toString(), Integer.parseInt(entry.getValue().toString()));
   }
```

With the hasmap being converted to  the sorting worked like a charm.